# Import and not used error

Tags: go

I'm getting below error with below import code:

Code:
    package main

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "github.com/emicklei/go-restful"
    "github.com/emicklei/go-restful/swagger"
    "./api"
)
```

Error:

```
.\main.go:9: imported and not used: "_/c_/Users/aaaa/IdeaProjects/app/src/api"
```

Is there a reason why the import is not working given that I have `package api` and files stored under api folder?

I'm using below to use `api` in main.go

```
func main() {
    // to see what happens in the package, uncomment the following
    restful.TraceLogger(log.New(os.Stdout, "[restful] ", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile))

    wsContainer := restful.NewContainer()
    api := ApiResource{map[string]OxiResp{}}
    api.registerLogin(wsContainer)
    api.registerAccount(wsContainer)
    api.registerLostLogin(wsContainer)
    api.registerWallet(wsContainer)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler looks for *actual use of a package* .. not the fact it exists.

You need to use something from that package.. or remove the import. E.g:

```
v := api.Something ...
```

If you don't use anything from that package in your source file .. you don't need to import it. That is, unless you want the `init` function to run. In which case, you can use the ignore notation `import _`.

EDIT:

After your update, it appears you're overwriting the package import here:

```
api := ApiResource{map[string]OxiResp{}}
```

That declares a variable called `api`. Now the compiler thinks its a variable, and so you're not actually using the `api` package.. you're using the `api` variable.

You have a few options.

Firstly, you can call that variable something else (probably what I would do):

```
apiv := ApiResource{map[string]OxiResp{}}
```

Or, alias your import (not what I would do.. but an option nonetheless):

```
import (
    // others here
    api_package "./api"
)
```

The problem is that the compiler is confused on what to use. The `api` package.. or the `api` variable you have declared.

You should also import the package via the `GOPATH` instead of relatively.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use relative imports.

If your `GOPATH` contains `/Users/aaaa/IdeaProjects/app/src`, then import your package as `api`.

Next, you're shadowing api with the assignment to `api :=`. Use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if your .go file has an error that is preventing the compiler from reaching the location where it is used.